# Backbone return the last model that was changed?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to create a view that renders a list of all the changes that happens to a model in the collection.

For instance on the main view that updates a model's "points" with a click, the model is updated the view is rendered, I want to have a view that listens to that occurrence and renders the information elsewhere.

Here is an example, I have three models kevin, mike, luke and the user clicks to add points to kevin the view captures that and renders content like... luke has scored 1 point.

I would create a feedView like below

```
var FeedView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '.live-feed',

    template: _.template($('#feedTemplate').html()),

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, "change", this.render);
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(max.toJSON()))          
        return this;
    }

});
```

I am not sure what to write to listen to the last change and return that?

Does that sound clear, I'd be glad to re-elaborate or provide more code/fiddles.

Comment: kevin, mike, luke are all part of collection used in FeedView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `change` event that you listen to on the collection will contain the model that has changed, and the model has a `previous()` method that can be used to retrieve the previous value.

I've created this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yukCY/) that I think does what you're after.

Comment: Fiddle looks good, obviously I need to do a little modification :) the most important part is how you render inside the `FeedView` right? Thats pretty much what I am focusing on now, because I have a view that already updates the model, there isn't any caveats I might miss?

Comment: Yes, I think the easiest way is to make the `FeedView` append a new feed item on each change. But I guess you could also store all changes in an array and then in `#feedTemplate` you loop through that array.

Comment: Yup, got it working nice man, you were spot on and thanks for going out your way to make a fiddle, especially a backbone.js fiddle they can be a pain having to include everything and get it setup properly, you surely deserve these points.

Comment: All I needed to do was focus on `FeedView`'s `playerChanged` method, pass in the model as the argument to that method and of course pass the collection to the instance and bam your code was plug and play, SWEET!

Answer (score 0):

```
render: function(model) {

    console.log(model.changed);
    // returns an object with all the changed values of the model
    // example: {points:5}

    console.log(model.previous('points'));
    // get the previous value for comparison

}
```